# Can't run 2 different scripts on the same yiigridview in yii

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

So I have this gridview:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'id'=>'symptoms-grid',
            'selectableRows'=>1, //ability to select one symptom at a time
            'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
            'htmlOptions'=>array('id'=>'symptomsSearchgrid'),
            'columns'=>array(
                'symptomCode',
                'title',
                'inclusions',
                'exclusions',
                'symptomCategory',

            ),
    )); ?>
```

And this javascript....script:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
        $( document ).ready(function() {

        $('#symptomSelectDiv').hide();

        $('#categorySelectDropDown').change(function(){
            $('#symptomSelectDiv').show();
            $('#symptoms-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
                data: $(this).serialize()
            });
            return false;
        });

        $('#symptomsSearchgrid table tbody tr').on('click', function() {

            var firstColVal = $(this).find('td:first-child').html();
            $('#symptomToBeSearched').val(firstColVal);
        });
        });
 ");
```

My problem is that I can only either get the

```
    $('#symptoms-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
            data: $(this).serialize()
        });
```

function to work or the:

```
 $('#symptomsSearchgrid table tbody tr').on('click', function() {

        var firstColVal = $(this).find('td:first-child').html();
        $('#symptomToBeSearched').val(firstColVal);
    });
```

one, and it seems quite random too. Basically in order to get the other function to "start working" I have to change the id (either the grid id or the DOM id) of one function to something different for the other function to work (while the other doesn't).

So let's say at first the update function works and the click function doesn't. Then I change the ID of update to something wrong and click works. Then I change the id of update back to the correct one, but it still doesn't work, yet click works. THen I change click to a wrong id and update starts working correctly. But again, if I change click to the correct id it doesn't work.....

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that your are giving your grid two id's one when creating it and one in htmloption.

Comment: If I only use one id though one of the functions doesn't work. The first ID is used by yii and the second is the table's DOM ID which I need for the javascript to work

Comment: You can use Yii generated Id for both purposes.

Comment: That's what I did at first but my second script wasn't working